# How to enumerate over an ALAssetsGroup in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried my best, but i got stuck in here. I wanted to import all photos from iPhone camera album. So i come up with this ALAssestsLibrary API.

```
 photoLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos), usingBlock: { group  in
        if group != nil

        {

        }

        }, failureBlock: { error in println("\(error)")})
```

how to add this line of code.

```
group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:groupEnumerAtion
```

I tried adding this but it does not showing any enumerateAssetsUsingBlock property.?

This is the actual code. !! In Objective-C

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock = ^(NSError *myerror)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"error occour =%@", [myerror localizedDescription]);
                };

                ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock groupEnumerAtion = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
                    {
                        if (result!=NULL)
                        {
                            if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
                            {
                                [self.g_imageArray addObject:result];
                            }
                        }
                };

                ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock
                libraryGroupsEnumeration = ^(ALAssetsGroup* group, BOOL* stop)
                    {
                        if (group == nil)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (group!=nil) {
                            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:groupEnumerAtion];
                        }
                        [self updatephotoList];
                };

                self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                [self.library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                usingBlock:libraryGroupsEnumeration 
                failureBlock:failureblock];
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `enumerationBlock` and `failureBlock` do not have the correct type.
For example, the enumeration block is defined as

```
typealias ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock = (ALAssetsGroup!, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void
```

which means that the argument is a closure taking `(ALAssetsGroup!, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>)` as parameters and returning `Void`:

```
{
     (group: ALAssetsGroup!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
     // ...
}
```

So your code should look like this:

```
photoLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos),
    usingBlock: {
        (group: ALAssetsGroup!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        if group != nil {
            group.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock({
                (asset: ALAsset!, index: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
                    // ...
                })
        }
    },
    failureBlock: {
        (myerror: NSError!) -> Void in
        println("error occurred: \(myerror.localizedDescription)")
    })
```

Due to the "automatic type inference" feature of Swift, you could this write also
as

```
photoLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos),
    usingBlock: {
        group, stop in
        if group != nil {
            group.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock({
                asset, index, stop in
                // ...
                })
        }
    },
    failureBlock: {
        myerror in
        println("error occurred: \(myerror.localizedDescription)")
    })
```

but in this case the first version is probably easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks! Had to change UnsafePointer to UnsafeMutablePointer though

Comment: @garafajon: You are completely right, this changed between Swift versions. I have updated the answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Note, that API is deprecated since iOS 9.0:

**Swift 5**

```
    let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
    library.enumerateGroups(withTypes: ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos), using: { (group, stop) -> Void in
        if let group = group {
            group.enumerateAssets({
                (asset, index, stop) -> Void in
                // ...
            })
        }
    },
    failureBlock: { myerror in
        print("error occurred: \(myerror)")
    })
```